# Downgrade from EF6 to EF5 .net framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, downgrade

I developed an MVC 4 app targeting the .net framework 4.5, but my server only supports 4.0, so I did the downgrade to .net framework 4.0 and reinstalled my nugget packages. I downgraded EF from 6 to 5 too and it is working fine in my machine, accessing the database, etc.
But when I run on the server, I get this error:

```
 Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +8508793
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +181
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +211
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders) +295
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString) +48
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ModelMatches(XDocument model) +44
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +65
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +52
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +239
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +19
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +186
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +190
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   ComponentList.Models.BaseBO`1.Listar() +79
   ComponentList.Areas.TR.Controllers.RegisterTypeController.Index() +98
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +240
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8836913
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I tried lot of things but couldnt solve this problem.

Comment: Remove EF completely and then install it using `install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0.0.`

Comment: I already tried this, it didn't work..

Comment: @Raiiy - why did you downgrade anyways?  EF6 supports .NET 4.0

Comment: I didnt know, I thougth EF6 was supported only by .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this

```
Database.SetInitializer<ComponentList.Models.ComponentListContext>(null);
```

to my Global.asax.cs

I still didnt understand why it worked, but it did.